# Are the additional constant-like things in an elementary diagram parameters or are they fresh but otherwise unconstrained constant symbols?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Are the additional constant-like things in an elementary diagram parameters or are they fresh but otherwise unconstrained constant symbols?

---

For context, I've seen the theorems saying that we have a homomorphism iff $B \models \text{Diag}(A)$ and we have an embedding iff $B \models \text{ElDiag}(A)$. I tried to prove one of them as an exercise and then realized I didn't know whether the elements of $A$ that occur in these diagrams are parameters or fresh-but-otherwise-unconstrained constant symbols.

Let $L$ be a language and let $A$ be an $L$-structure.

The [elementary diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_diagram) is the set of $L_A$ literals that are true in $A$.

An elementary diagram is not just built out of the symbols of $L$, we additionally get a fresh $c_a$ for each $a$ in $A$.

It seems to me that there's a small difference between considering each $c_a$ as a *fresh constant symbol* vs *a parameter*.

And that would be what kind of map we are promised when $B \models \text{ElDiag}(A)$.

If $\text{ElDiag}(A)$ contains just fresh constant symbols, then we're promised an embedding $e : A \to B$.

However, if $\text{ElDiag}(A)$ contains *parameters*, then by taking $B \models \text{ElDiag}(A)$ we're also requiring $A$ to be a substructure of $B$, since every element of $A$ gives rise to a parameter occurring somewhere in the diagram.

So, we're promised an embedding $i : A \to B$ that's an inclusion map. In these circumstances, I *think* we're promised that $A$ is an elementary substructure of $B$, but I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the distinct you're drawing here between parameters and fresh constant symbols, but models of the elementary diagram are elementary extensions of the given structure. When forming the elementary diagram by taking formulas in $\mathcal{L}(A)$ you are interpreting the new parameters (i.e. new constant symbols) in the natural way i.e. as the element that serves as its index.

Comment: The distinction that I'm drawing is whether the fresh constant symbols are constrained to be interpreted in a particular way ... which would make them parameters. It sounds like they are ... which would mean that $B \models \text{ElDiag}(A)$ implies that $B$ is a superstructure of $A$ and not just that the signature of $B$ is a superset of the signature of $A$, thanks.

Comment: You seem to use the terminology "elementary diagram" to mean what is usually called just the diagram. The usual meaning of "elementary diagram of $A$" is the complete theory (including sentences with quantifiers) of the $L_A$-structure $\overline A$ obtained from the $L$-structure $A$ by interpreting each of the new constant symbols as the corresponding element of $A$.

Comment: This "standard" interpretation of the new constant symbols is part of the definition of the particular structure $\overline A$. It is not a requirement for other $L_A$-structures like your $B$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, THANK YOU. That makes a lot of sense. So $\text{Diag}^+$ is the positive diagram and promises you a homomorphism (when $B \models \text{Diag}^+(A)$), $\text{Diag}$ is the (atomic) diagram and promises you an embedding, and $\text{ElDiag}$ is the elementary diagram and promises you an elementary embedding. It sounds like we're only calling the $c_A$'s parameters because we're using their standard interpretation to assess whether they belong in the diagram in the first place, not to assess the truth in other structures of sentences that contain them.

Comment: @GregNisbet Your comment is correct, except that I wouldn't call Diag the atomic diagram, because it also contains negations of atomic sentences.  Also, I don't usually talk about parameters at all; variables and constants are enough for me.